# OpAmp on Multisim keep amplifying over Gain Bandwidth Product

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain-bandwidth-product

I have below circuit on Multisim with Current source replicating Photodiode and opAmp amplify current. However opAmp keep amplifying even at very high frequencies without considering Gain Bandwidth Product.

How should I edit adjust the model not to disregard it?

[image]

Comment: No one can answer that without the details of the model.

Comment: What are your design parameters? I can tell you right now this design is not what the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lf351-955012.pdf) recommends for measurement.

Comment: @Colin transimpedance amplifier for Photodiode

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful Apologizes, I edited my comment.

Comment: @Colin Can you please elaborate on design parameters? other than this in another opamp from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/609/62689f-3125371.pdf) , GBP is 500mHz however they claim that it can get 65mHz bandwidth at 20k ohm gain in transimpedance mode. I'm very confused

Comment: For a transimpedance amplifier, the bandwidth (ideally, and neglecting parasitics) is essentially the unity-gain bandwidth of the amplifier.  The diode is modelled as a current source (infinite small-signal impedance) so the *voltage* gain seen from the non-inverting terminal is unity.  (1+Rf/infinity).  What bandwidth are you expecting and what are you getting from simulation?

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful mHz is millihertz, I think you mean MHz.  For the LT op-amp you linked  it's entirely reasonable to get 65 MHz BW with a GBW of 500 MHz and 20 K of transimpedance.  Per my prevous comment, you don't divide the GBW by the transimpedance to get the expected bandwidth.

Comment: @JohnD How should I calculate it? everyone says as you are increasing the gain which the feedback resistor, bandwidth should go down. Can you please guide me on this? For instance please have a look at this YT video [ref](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UooUGC7tNRg)

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful Look at page 11 of the following datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa846.pdf

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful Also here: https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/01-930-00-00-00-66-60-61/Op-Amp-Bandwidth-for-Transimpedance-Amplifiers.pdf

Comment: @JohnD thank you. going through it now. just wondering why everybody explains it the way I was referring to?

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful Dividing GBW by gain applies to voltage gain (seen from the non-inverting input).  It is the standard way to estimate the bandwidth of a voltage amplifier.  However, a transimpedance amplifier isn't a voltage amplifier and requires a different approach.

Comment: @JohnD Thank you very much. Much appreciated

Comment: @JohnD On top of pole response, I'm seeing 2 different equations in sources you shared for the calculation of 3db bandwidth.